# Use 3 tables Laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

My application has 3 tables that are related to each other: users, subscribers, subscriber_tokens.

```
users:
id   | name    | username
56   | Ngoni   | ngoni

subscribers:
id  | user_id   | client_id 
1   |    30     | 2
16  |    56     | 2

subscriber_tokens:
id | token        | user_id  | client_id  
1  | e7ij3l00J... |    56    |     2
```

I have defined my relationships as below:

`User.php` Model

```
public function subscribers()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Subscriber', 'client_id', 'id');
}
```

`SubscriberToken.php` Model

```
public function subscriber()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

`Subscriber.php` Model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Now I have defined a function that is supposed to link the 3 tables like this:

```
public function subscriberTokens(){
    $subscriber_ids = $this->subscribers()->pluck('id')->toArray();
    return SubscriberToken::whereHas('subscriber', function ($query) use($subscriber_ids){
        $query->whereIn('subscribers.id', $subscriber_ids);
    })->get();
}
```

So when I execute the function the following error occurs:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'subscribers.id' in  'where clause' (SQL: select * from `subscriber_tokens` where exists (select * from `users` where `subscriber_tokens`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` and `subscribers`.`id` in (1, 16)))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public function subscriberTokens(){
    $subscriber_ids = $this->subscribers()->pluck('id')->toArray();
    return SubscriberToken::whereHas('subscriber', function ($query) use($subscriber_ids){
        $query->whereIn('user_id', $subscriber_ids);
    })->get();
}
```